# 'signatures: Array<(out) Signature!>!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I got this `printHashKey` function and it works well.

```
fun printHashKey() {
    try {
        val info : PackageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
        for (signature in info.signatures) {
            val md: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
            md.update(signature.toByteArray())
            val hashKey = String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0))
            Log.i("TAG", "printHashKey() Hash Key: $hashKey")
        }
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        Log.e("TAG", "printHashKey()", e)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("TAG", "printHashKey()", e)
    }
}
```

but there's a warning sign :

- `GET_SIGNATURES: Int` is deprecated. Deprecated in Java.
- `signatures: Array<(out) Signature!>!` is deprecated. `Deprecated` in Java.

So I changed `GET_SIGNATURES` to `GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES`

```
fun printHashKey() {
    try {
        val info : PackageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES)
        for (signature in info.signatures) {
            val md: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
            md.update(signature.toByteArray())
            val hashKey = String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0))
            Log.i("TAG", "printHashKey() Hash Key: $hashKey")
        }
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        Log.e("TAG", "printHashKey()", e)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("TAG", "printHashKey()", e)
    }
}
```

And I still got this warning.

- `signatures: Array<(out) Signature!>!` is deprecated. `Deprecated` in Java.

I know I can just ignore this warning, but I want to fix it.
What can I use instead of `signatures`?

Answer (score 1):

From Android P you should use `signingInfo` instead

Full code:

```
val signatures = with(packageManager) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
       getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES)
                        .signingInfo
                        .apkContentsSigners
    } else {
       getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
                        .signatures
    }
}
```

And afters this you also could add this lines above your function to suppress warnings:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
@SuppressLint("PackageManagerGetSignatures")
```